# How to create a hotkey to make left alt like right alt?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 18.04

In Ubuntu 16, there was a hotkey option in the keyboard settings named something like "special key", which allowed me to type characters like <>{}

By default I have to type those characters by using the right alt.

In Ubuntu 18, this hotkey option is gone from the keyboard hotkeys, so how can I achieve this functionality now?

To put it more simply, instead of having to press Right "Alt + >" to type >, I want to press "left Alt + >" instead (or even more ideally "ctrl + left alt + >" if it is at all possible)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install *Tweaks* (the `gnome-tweaks` package)
- Open *Tweaks*
- Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level